# watched scope is empty after route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller I'm using for 3 different views that collects data. I'm watching 2 scopes in it.
This is an excerpt:

```
  // predefine place before Google Maps API GET
  $scope.place = {
    formatted_address: '',
    url: ''
  };

  // watch place in case of change (doesn't work otherwise)
  $scope.$watch('place', function () {
    $scope.poll.Poll.Location    = $scope.place.formatted_address;
    $scope.poll.Poll.UrlLocation = $scope.place.url;
  });
```

Everything works fine on view 1, the `$scope.poll.Poll.Location` and the `$scope.poll.Poll.Location` gets filled with data of the Google Maps api.

But when I click on a button which changes my route `(ui-sref="view2")`, which is using the same controller, the scopes are empty.

How can I transfer the watched scopes between multiple views with the same controller?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple states using the same controller, then both states get it's own instance of the controller. You have to pass the data as a param to the second state.

Like this:`ui-sref="view2({poll: poll})"`

Don't forget to add the param to the state definition in $stateProvider.

```
$stateProvider.state("homepageState", {
    url: "/home/",
    templateUrl: "templates/homePage.html",
    controller: "HomePageController",
    params: {
       poll: null //initial
    }
});
```

In your controller you can get the value by calling `$stateParams.poll`

You also could make use of angular [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). A service is instantiated only once and is reusable.

If you have to wait for data from an unknown source, then you have to take a look at [Promise.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> **when(value, [successCallback], [errorCallback], [progressCallback]);**
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able
>   promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an
>   object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes
>   from a source that can't be trusted.

Comment: Okay, how does the param definition need to look like?

Comment: I have added it to my answer

Answer (score -1):

Put then on `$rootScope` may works

```
$scope.$watch('place', function () {
  $rootScope.poll.Poll.Location    = $scope.place.formatted_address;
  $rootScope.poll.Poll.UrlLocation = $scope.place.url;
});
```

Comment: I don't think the rootScope is a proper way to handle this

Comment: if he changes the route all the current scope is lost, put then on rootScope will persist the data no matter which controller he is in

Comment: but to work you have to put all the `poll` object in the `$rootScope` otherwise you will get errors

Comment: You are creating a unnecessary watch in the rootScope that never will be cleaned up. The rootScope is meant to be used for global functionality. $watch is a dirty checking if some value has been modified and could couse performance problems. This would be the last option if you already tried the proper way.